# Prevent wrapping without nowrap

Tags: html, css

I have a div like this :

---

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="wrap">
           <div class="text">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.container {
    position: relative;
    padding:20px;
    background: #ccc;
    float:left;
}
.text {
    position: relative;
    float:left;
    background: lightblue;
}

.wrap {
    position: absolute;
}
```

---

Is it possible to avoid the wrapping of .wrap without using whitespace:nowrap or by specifying width to any div

http://jsfiddle.net/WmcjM/71/

Answer (score 0):

Remove `position: relative` from the `.container` style.

Comment: This is a tricky solution. It "works" because in that particular example there isn't any other relative positioned element between `.wrap` and the root. And I put "works" between quotes because the result is not the same as with `white-space` (there is still wrapping that doesn't happen with `white-space:nowrap`)

Comment: Any other solution without changing position attribute ?